# How can I flag a regular time series with a irregular error sign in R?

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series

I have a straight sequence of time series, for example:

```
library(lubridate)
start = parse_date_time("2018-01-01","%Y-%m-%d")
end = parse_date_time("2018-01-02","%Y-%m-%d")
series = seq(start,end,by=600)

> series
[1] "2018-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 00:10:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 00:20:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 00:30:00 UTC"
[5] "2018-01-01 00:40:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 00:50:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 01:10:00 UTC"
[9] "2018-01-01 01:20:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 01:30:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 01:40:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 01:50:00 UTC"
[13] "2018-01-01 02:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 02:10:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 02:20:00 UTC" "2018-01-01 02:30:00 UTC"...
```

And I also have a vector of irregular status, for example:

```
error = data.frame(
on = parse_date_time(c("2018-01-01 00:13:57","2018-01-01 01:01:44"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
off = parse_date_time(c("2018-01-01 00:21:32","2018-01-01 02:33:45"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
)

> error
                   on                 off
1 2018-01-01 00:13:57 2018-01-01 00:21:32
2 2018-01-01 01:01:44 2018-01-01 02:33:45
```

How can I flag my series with the error just like below?

```
> flag 
                         series        error
  [1] "2018-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"         "OK"
  [2] "2018-01-01 00:10:00 UTC"         "OK"
  [3] "2018-01-01 00:20:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
  [4] "2018-01-01 00:30:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
  [5] "2018-01-01 00:40:00 UTC"         "OK"
  [6] "2018-01-01 00:50:00 UTC"         "OK"
  [7] "2018-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"         "OK"
  [8] "2018-01-01 01:10:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
  [9] "2018-01-01 01:20:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
 [10] "2018-01-01 01:30:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
 [11] "2018-01-01 01:40:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
 [12] "2018-01-01 01:50:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
 [13] "2018-01-01 02:00:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
 [14] "2018-01-01 02:10:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
 [15] "2018-01-01 02:20:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
 [16] "2018-01-01 02:30:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
 [17] "2018-01-01 02:40:00 UTC"      "ERROR"
 [18] "2018-01-01 02:50:00 UTC"         "OK"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `map_lgl`, because `lubridate` intervals play funny with `dplyr` functions for me. Note that I use `ceiling_date` on `off` to reproduce your desired output, even though it's not obvious to me why the last row counts as `ERROR` since, for example, row 4 in the output `"2018-01-01 00:30:00 UTC"` is after the first `off` value `"2018-01-01 00:21:32"`. The key parts are simply the creation of intervals with `interval` (or alternatively, `on %--% off`) and then the use of `any(%within%)` to return a logical value for whether a given value in the series is inside one of the error intervals. `ifelse` lets us convert the values into character flags.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
start = parse_date_time("2018-01-01","%Y-%m-%d")
end = parse_date_time("2018-01-02","%Y-%m-%d")
series = seq(start,end,by=600)
error = data.frame(
  on = parse_date_time(c("2018-01-01 00:13:57","2018-01-01 01:01:44"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
  off = parse_date_time(c("2018-01-01 00:21:32","2018-01-01 02:33:45"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
) %>%
  mutate(
    off = ceiling_date(off, unit = "10 minutes"),
    intvs = interval(on, off)
  )

series %>%
  tibble(dttm = .) %>%
  bind_cols(status = map_lgl(series, ~ any(. %within% error$intvs))) %>%
  mutate(status = ifelse(status == TRUE, "ERROR", "OK")) %>%
  print(n = 20)
#> # A tibble: 145 x 2
#>    dttm                status
#>    <dttm>              <chr> 
#>  1 2018-01-01 00:00:00 OK    
#>  2 2018-01-01 00:10:00 OK    
#>  3 2018-01-01 00:20:00 ERROR 
#>  4 2018-01-01 00:30:00 ERROR 
#>  5 2018-01-01 00:40:00 OK    
#>  6 2018-01-01 00:50:00 OK    
#>  7 2018-01-01 01:00:00 OK    
#>  8 2018-01-01 01:10:00 ERROR 
#>  9 2018-01-01 01:20:00 ERROR 
#> 10 2018-01-01 01:30:00 ERROR 
#> 11 2018-01-01 01:40:00 ERROR 
#> 12 2018-01-01 01:50:00 ERROR 
#> 13 2018-01-01 02:00:00 ERROR 
#> 14 2018-01-01 02:10:00 ERROR 
#> 15 2018-01-01 02:20:00 ERROR 
#> 16 2018-01-01 02:30:00 ERROR 
#> 17 2018-01-01 02:40:00 ERROR 
#> 18 2018-01-01 02:50:00 OK    
#> 19 2018-01-01 03:00:00 OK    
#> 20 2018-01-01 03:10:00 OK    
#> # ... with 125 more rows
```

Created on 2018-03-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).